# dynamic table building

Tags: javascript

I'm building a html table dynamically, using an array of values. I'm wanting to create this table, starting with the first column, moving right. For example, I have the array:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

My table should look like this:

```
a   c   e
b   d   f
```

If i have defined the number of columns I wish to use, I loop `Math.ceil(array.length / number_of_columns)` number of times to get each row. Within that loop, I loop `number_of_columns` times to get each column. To find out with value in the array I need I use this formula: `array_index = (row_column_number * number_of_rows) + row_number`. Is that a correct formula? Also, is this the best way of doing this?

Comment: Your data isn't an array.  This `[0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f']` looks more like an object `{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f'}`.  Is it supposed to be an object?

Comment: are you sure you need to create a table and not divs with `float:left;`?

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry, I didn't write it in an array, I was trying to show the indexes. I guess I was thinking in terms of PHP where you can write the index before the value.

Comment: @deathApril I'd prefer to use a table, but I'm open to other ideas if it's good enough.

Comment: @LordZardeck - then please edit your question to include a properly formatted javascript array.

Comment: @jfriend00 in javascript can you write an array setting the indexes?

Comment: @LordZardeck - No - you don't declare indexes when declaring array data.  Since your array is entirely sequential, you can just declare each element with commas between as Umesh did in their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. It is the only (best) way of doing this with core java script.                                                                                  Find below the test java script code required for you.

```
<html>
<head>
<style> .mytable tr td{ margin:10px;border:1px dotted green;width:100px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onload(){       
        var arr=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g','h','i','j','k'];
        var number_of_columns=3; // enter number of columns 
        var nrRows=Math.ceil(arr.length / number_of_columns);      
        var root=document.getElementById('mydiv');
        var tab=document.createElement('table');
        tab.className="mytable";
        var tbo=document.createElement('tbody');
        var row, cell;
        for(var i=0;i<nrRows;i++){
            row=document.createElement('tr');
            for(var j=0;j<number_of_columns;j++){
                cell=document.createElement('td');
                cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i*number_of_columns+j]));
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }
            tbo.appendChild(row);

        }
        tab.appendChild(tbo);
        root.appendChild(tab);
}
window.onload=onload;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```